# SubSonic 3 ignoring columns in Select()

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have a table like so..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locations_Hours](
  [LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [sun_open] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [sun_close] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [mon_open] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [mon_close] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [tue_open] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [tue_close] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [wed_open] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [wed_close] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [thu_open] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [thu_close] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [fri_open] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [fri_close] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [sat_open] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [sat_close] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
  [StoreNumber] [int] NULL,
  [LocationHourID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Locations_Hours] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [LocationHourID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And SubSonic 3 is generating a class with the following properties

```
int LocationID
string monopen
string monclose
string tueopen 
string tueclose
string wedopen 
string wedclose
string thuopen 
string thuclose
string friopen 
string friclose
string satopen 
string satclose
string sunopen 
string sunclose
int? StoreNumber
int LocationHourID
```

When I try to perform a query against this class like so..

```
var result = DB.LocationHours.Where(o => o.LocationID == _locationId);
```

This is the resulting SQL query that SubSonic generates.

```
SELECT [t0].[LocationHourID], [t0].[LocationID], [t0].[StoreNumber]
FROM [dbo].[Locations_Hours] AS t0
WHERE ([t0].[LocationID] = 4019)
```

I cannot figure out why SubSonic is omitting the `nvarchar` fields when it generates the SELECT statement. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What are you using SimpleRepo, ActiveRecord templates or Linq templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't ever able to solve this problem. I ended up just executing a plain old DataReader and 'manually' populated my objects.

If anyone comes along later with an answer, I will change the accepted answer.